# Getting correct mouse position on Canvas when canvas size is relative?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, html5-canvas

The problem is the following, my canvas width and height is relative to its parents. In css, its width and height is set to 95%. That causes my getMousePosition function to not work properly, meaning that when I click on a canvas point, the actual point where say a rectangle is drawn is far from the observed clicked point.

Here is the html stuff

```
<div class="Container">
            <div id = 'left-div'>
                <canvas class = "Blackboard" id = "blackboard-canvas" >

                </canvas>
            </div>                  
            <div id='right-div'>
                <div id = 'tools-div'>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#colorOption'>Color Options</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#toolbar-option'>Tool Bar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id='colorOption'>
                        <canvas id='color-option-canvas' >

                        </canvas>
                    </div>
                    <div id='toolbar-option'>
                        Tool bar options goes here
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <br style="clear:both;"/>
        </div>
```

and the relavent css

```
.Blackboard{

border-style: ridge;
border-color: gray;
border-width: 5px; 
width: 96%;
height: 96%;
cursor: crosshair;
position: relative;
-webkit-border-radius: 16px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 7px #0a0505;
  };

 .Blackboard:active{
cursor: crosshair;
  }

 .Container{
border-color: #666;
border-width: 10px;
border-style: inset;
background-color: gray;
width: 700px;
height: 400px;
 }

 #right-div, #left-div{
height: 100%;
 }
 #left-div{
float: left;
width: 60%;
 }
 #right-div{
float: right;
background-color: black;
width: 40%;
 }
```

Is there a way to 'normalize' it or or something?

EDIT:

here is a the jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EZktE/

Comment: ... and the `getMousePosition` function? Maybe make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this so people don't have to copy all this stuff to some test-environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your canvas is assuming the default `<canvas>` size attributes of `width=300 height=150`.  Those attributes set the coordinate system for the canvas, independently of any CSS-derived width and height attributes.

To resolve it, put this immediately after the line that finds the canvas element:

```
this.canvas.width = this.canvas.offsetWidth;
this.canvas.height = this.canvas.offsetHeight;
```

This also copes with the 96% scaling factor relative to its parent.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/9JtfW/

NB: your own fiddle doesn't work because your `Blackboard` class was created inside jsfiddle's default `$(document).ready()` handler so wasn't in scope when invoked from the inline handler in the HTML.

Comment: Thank you. So the this.canvasOffset* is the actual dimension of the canvas?

Comment: strictly speaking it includes the margin, border and padding too.  You should probably actually use `$(this.canvas).width()` etc but then you'll need to change your mouse position calculation to subtract your border and margin sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just substract the OffsetX and OffsetY properties of your canvas DOMElement with the x and y you retrieve.

This will work correctly untill the user starts zooming in, thats a fairly difficult problem to tackle.